# Please help me find user **uncovery**!"

Tags: discussion, users

I am very sorry to upset your protocol for asking questions. I came across the site about three hours ago while researching Japanese customs for a Master's degree in Forensic Nursing.  Although I have scholarly articles, I would like to give APA citation credit to user **uncovery** for his/her response about communications. 
I can't figure out how to directly make contact, so I ask for your help!

Comment: Here they are: https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/3778/uncovery.

Comment: Thanks Shadow Wizard! I did come across that page, but I couldn't find the name (which perhaps he or she doesn't want to share.) I've done due diligence in trying to request permission from the author, but Zach Lipton provided me with an alternative idea. Thank you so much!

Comment: I guess I can't comment yet, but I'll try once again. Thank you for taking care of those details. I took the risk in order to quickly find an answer, but you are correct, it's wise to conceal that.

Comment: Relevant: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/49760/citing-stack-overflow-discussions

Comment: Welcome @Sunnypup! Thanks for caring so much about giving citation credit to a user!  Not everyone would do that! Thanks @Zach Lipton for teaching me something new about APA style of citations!  Sunnypup, I see that you've tried to do things yourself, but our system is different from others, and there's a learning curve. I'm active on other SE communities and am still learning! Please don't let critical comments keep you away from the community!

Comment: I'm not sure it's necessary to remove identifying information against someone's will ... plenty of people post on SE with their full name and Sunnypup didn't post anything beyond her name

Comment: @Giorgio The contact details are still available from the question before it was migrated (accessible through the question history). It would probably be best to remove that question, too.

Answer (score 24):

[Uncovery's user profile](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/3778/uncovery) is available, and it contains a link to [his/her website](https://uncovery.net/). There's a contact form there if you want to send a message.

However, you should generally be able to just cite the answer directly (check with your instructor to see if this is acceptable for your course); it's not generally necessary to contact the author before citing internet resources. APA style encourages you to [cite the author's name as it is given in the source](https://blog.apastyle.org/apastyle/2012/02/how-to-cite-pseudonyms.html), so you can simply cite it to uncovery and provide the URL and other details.

Comment: Weird that someone finds it easier to create an account and write a question rather than take a moment to scan for the links that are in plain view.

Comment: Weird? Actually, I tried the links. They kept buffering and loading and buffering and unloading, and were completely unreliable. Things are not always as they appear, so kindly reserve judgment.

Comment: Zach, thank you for that tip. My instructor encouraged me to find uncovery's name. However, I have no interest in making an earnest pursuit only to be met with comments that my methods are "weird" by uninformed individuals. I will take your advice.

Comment: I'll try again to reply. I DID follow the links. They didn't lead me to a name, and simply kept buffering, for hours. I'm trying to do right by uncovery in crediting him. I think it's weird that you make a judgment without knowing the facts. I guess there will always be those types.

Comment: @Sunnypup Please include all relevant information in your question. How were we supposed to know that you'd tried to follow the links and they didn't work for you? (Especially when they seem to work just fine for everybody else.) If you'd mentioned this, Zach wouldn't have wasted his time telling you to do something you've already done.

Comment: From a quick scan, it appears that uncovery's website might be inaccessible or blocked in some countries, and might be inaccessible in others for technical reasons unrelated to censorship. This isn't the place to work out those sorts of problems, but @Sunnypup might wish to visit our sister site [su] for help sorting out being unable to access the website.

Answer (score 0):

In case you can't access to his website and take up contact directly, on it there's a link to his public Facebook page. The Facebook username is *uncovery.photo*.

I wish good luck for taking up contact with him. Be aware though that, judging from his posts, he hasn't been active on this site since June 2015.

Comment: You don't need to judge from posts. In the user profile it shows that the user visited the site on the 6th of this month.